# Why does רש"י sometimes say "בגמרא מפרש", and sometimes say "בגמרא מפרש טעמא"?

Tags: rashi, language

For example, Rashi on Mishnah on Bava Kama Daf 27a:

- **ושברה פטור** - בגמרא מפרש טעמא
- '**בעל החבית חייב** - מפרש בגמ

Comment: I think מפרש בגמרא is a more generic comment that assumes it's obvious what needs explanation. Sometimes Rashi is more specific and says what will be explained. In this case it's the reason that needs elaboration, hence בגמרא מפרש טעמא. The follow-up is the same, so it doesn't need to be spelled out again.

Comment: See also: https://lif.ac.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/frenkel_a.pdf

Comment: Sometimes the Gemara explains the reason and sometimes the Gemara explains the specifics of the case, and the reason is self understood. In the case you mentioned, the first rashi refers to the Gemara that explains why the person is patur to pay even though he should’ve been watching where he was going. The second rashi refers to the Gemara that explains it’s only if the person slipped but if he broke it and hurt himself that way, then the owner is patur.